# spring-boot r2dbc: How to read enum as string and convert it to enum

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, enums, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc

I have an enum like

```
enum class Gender(val value: String) {
    MALE("male"),
    FEMALE("female"),
    DIVERSE("diverse"),
    UNKNOWN("unknown");

    companion object {
        fun fromValue(value: String): Gender {
            entries.forEach { v ->
                if (v.value == value) {
                    return v
                }
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("No Gender found for value=${value}")
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of a User model:

```
@Table(name = "users")
class User (
    @Column("gender")
    var gender: Gender = Gender.DIVERSE,

    @Column("first_name")
    var firstName: String? = null,

    @Column("last_name")
    var lastName: String? = null,

    @Column("country_code")
    var countryCode: String? = null,

    @Column("phone_number")
    var phoneNumber: String? = null,

    @Column("password")
    var password: String? = null,

    @Column("email")
    var email: String? = null
): BaseEntity()
```

I have registered custom @ReadingConvertes and @WritingConverters. The Writing converter seems to work, but the reading converter doesn't seem to work.

UPDATE:
Here is the writing converter. This component works fine and the lower case string values are written in the db.

```
@WritingConverter
class GenderWritingConverter : Converter<Gender, String> {
    override fun convert(source: Gender): String =
        source.value
}
```

Here is the Readingconverter. This converter is not called, even if it is registered as a custom converter.

```
@ReadingConverter
class GenderReadingConverter : Converter<String, Gender> {
    override fun convert(source: String): Gender {
        return Gender.fromValue(source)
    }
}
```

Here is how I am registering it to the r2dbc config:

```
@Configuration
class R2dbcConfig(
    private val connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory
): AbstractR2dbcConfiguration() {

    override fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory = connectionFactory
    @Bean
    override fun r2dbcCustomConversions(): R2dbcCustomConversions =
        R2dbcCustomConversions(storeConversions, 
            mutableListOf(GenderReadingConverter(),GenderWritingConverter()))
}
```

While converting the value from the db, I have following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Gender.diverse
```

Comment: It looks like you're persisting the enum in lower case.  Consider changing your reader to `return Gender.fromValue(source.toUpperCase())`

Comment: You are right.  But that's the value of the enum. The same code works with JPA using AttributeConverter

Comment: Now I'm confused, I thought your question was how to read it as a String and return an enum?

Comment: Correct.  The snall letter values are stired in the db as string. I want to read from db and convert it to the corresponding Enum

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for.  My first comment explained what you need to change in your ReadingConverter to make this work.

Comment: Try using `@Enumerated(STRING)`

Comment: The problem is, the reading converter is never invoked.  The writing converter,  which I have not shown here, is invoked

Comment: Let me update the question by adding the writingConverter which is working fine.